# Precalc word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Can someone to point me in the right direction for this math problem I have on my homework? I don't know where to begin on this.

> The elk population in a certain region is given by the function E(t) = 1050 + 120sin(2t/5), where time is t measured in years. What is the largest number of elk present in the region at anytime?

Comment: What is the maximum value of the sine function?

Comment: That's the entire problem.

Comment: Recall the definition of the sine function. Given an angle in a triangle, the sine function is the ratio of the length of the opposite side to the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

What is the maximum value of $\sin x$? Then, what is the maximum value of $\sin(2t/5)$? Next, what is the maximum value of $120\sin(2t/5)$? Finally, what is the maximum value of $1050+120\sin(2t/5)$? That is the largest amount of elk present at any time.